# import product data programmatically using csv

Tags: magento2, product, import, cron, crontab

I am new in magento 2

I am trying to import product data programmatically using csv file.

The Error is shown below

[image]

My Folder and code structure are following.

This is My registration file.

`Vendor/Modulename/regis.xml`

```
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'vendorName_moduleName', __DIR__);
```

This is my module.xml file

`Vendor/Modulename/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

This is cron script file Crontab.php

`Vendor/Modulename/etc/crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="importproduct">
        <job instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Cron\Test" method="execute" name="VendorName_ModuleName_cron">
            <schedule>5 0 26 8 4</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

This is cron script file Test.php

`Vendor/Modulename/Cron/Test.php`

```
Class Test{
    $file = fopen('var/import/new.csv', 'r', '"'); // set path to the CSV file
    if ($file !== false) {

    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');

    // used for updating product stock - and it's important that it's inside the while loop
    $stockRegistry = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');

    // add logging capability

    $header = fgetcsv($file); // get data headers and skip 1st row

    // enter the min number of data fields you require that the new product will have (only if you want to standardize the import)
    $required_data_fields = 3;

    while ( $row = fgetcsv($file, 3000, ",") ) {

        $data_count = count($row);
        if ($data_count < 1) {
            continue;
        }

        // used for setting the new product data
        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');         
        $data = array();
        $data = array_combine($header, $row);

        $sku = $data['sku'];
        if ($data_count < $required_data_fields) {
            $logger->info("Skipping product sku " . $sku . ", not all required fields are present to create the product.");
            continue;
        }

        $name = $data['name'];
        $description = $data['description'];
        $shortDescription = $data['short_description'];
        $qty = trim($data['qty']);
        $price = trim($data['price']);

        try {
            $product->setTypeId('simple') // type of product you're importing
                    ->setStatus(1) // 1 = enabled
                    ->setAttributeSetId(4) // In Magento 2.2 attribute set id 4 is the Default attribute set (this may vary in other versions)
                    ->setName($name)
                    ->setSku($sku)
                    ->setPrice($price)
                    ->setTaxClassId(0) // 0 = None
                    ->setCategoryIds(array(2, 3)) // array of category IDs, 2 = Default Category
                    ->setDescription($description)
                    ->setShortDescription($shortDescription)
                    ->setUrlKey($url_key) // you don't need to set it, because Magento does this by default, but you can if you need to
                    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) // Default Website ID
                    ->setStoreId(0) // Default store ID
                    ->setVisibility(4) // 4 = Catalog & Search
                    ->save();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $logger->info('Error importing product sku: '.$sku.'. '.$e->getMessage());
            continue;
        }

        try {
            $stockItem = $stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);

            if ($stockItem->getQty() != $qty) {
                $stockItem->setQty($qty);
                if ($qty > 0) {
                    $stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
                }
                $stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $logger->info('Error importing stock for product sku: '.$sku.'. '.$e->getMessage());
            continue;
        }
        unset($product);
    }
    fclose($file);
}
}
```

Comment: Your class should have execute method and put all code in execute method. also check `php -l Test.php` for grammatically mistake

Answer (score 1):

Import product data programmatically using CSV- file.

Step 1 : create a custom module. Example : `WebbyTroops_ProductSync`

Step 2 : Create custom cron :

Add `crontab.xml` file to define new cron tab, path `WebbyTroops/ProductSync/etc/crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="import_products" instance="WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Cron\ImportProducts" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Add cron Class to execute : `WebbyTroops/ProductSync/Cron/ImportProducts.php`

```
<?php

namespace WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Cron;

use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Adapter;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class ImportProducts
{
    /**
     * Import field separator.
     */
    const FIELD_FIELD_SEPARATOR = '_import_field_separator';

    /**
     * @var \WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Model\Import\Product
     */
    protected $productImport;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import $import
     */
    protected $import;

    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Model\Import\Product $productImport
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryManager
     * @param \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import $import
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Model\Import\Product $productImport,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryManager,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import $import,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->productImport = $productImport;
        $this->directoryManager = $directoryManager;
        $this->import = $import;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
 {
        try {
            $varDirectory = $this->directoryManager->getPath('var');
            $productCsvFileName = "product-csv";

            $file = $varDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $productCsvFileName . '.csv';

            $postData = [
                'entity' => 'catalog_product',
                'behavior' => 'append',
                'validation_strategy' => 'validation-stop-on-errors',
                'allowed_error_count' => 1,
                '_import_field_separator' => '',
                '_import_multiple_value_separator' => '',
                '_import_empty_attribute_value_constant' => '__EMPTY__VALUE__',
                'import_images_file_dir' => $varDirectory . '/import/images'
            ];

            $this->import->setData($postData);
            $source = $this->_getSourceAdapter($file);
            $isValid = $this->import->validateSource($source);

            if ($isValid) {
                $this->productImport->startImport($varDirectory . '/import/sync');
            } else {
                $errros = $this->import->getErrorAggregator()->getAllErrors();
                $this->logger->info(count($errros) . 'error(s) found while importing products from Vend.');
                foreach ($errros as $error) {
                    $this->logger->error($error->getErrorMessage() . ' at row number ' . $error->getRowNumber() . ' and coloumn name ' . $error->getColumnName());
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info('Something went wrong while importing products');
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns source adapter object.
     *
     * @param string $sourceFile Full path to source file
     * @return AbstractSource
     * @throws FileSystemException
     */
    protected function _getSourceAdapter($sourceFile)
    {
        return Adapter::findAdapterFor(
            $sourceFile,
            $this->filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::ROOT),
            $this->import->getData(self::FIELD_FIELD_SEPARATOR)
        );
    }
}
```

Add product Import Class : path `WebbyTroops/ProductSync/Model/Import/Product.php` file :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Model\Import;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface;
use Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\AbstractSource;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Processor;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

/**
 * Product Import
 *
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import
     */
    protected $import;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ImageDirectoryBaseProvider
     */
    protected $imagesDirProvider;

    /**
     * @var \WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Logger\Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import $import
     * @param \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ImageDirectoryBaseProvider $imageDirectoryBaseProvider
     * @param \WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Logger\Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import $import,
        \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ImageDirectoryBaseProvider $imageDirectoryBaseProvider,
        \WebbyTroops\ProductSync\Logger\Logger $logger
    ) {
        $this->import = $import;
        $this->imagesDirProvider = $imageDirectoryBaseProvider;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function startImport($imagePath)
    {
        $data = [
            'entity' => 'catalog_product',
            'behavior' => 'append',
            'validation_strategy' => 'validation-stop-on-errors',
            'allowed_error_count' => 1,
            '_import_field_separator' => '',
            '_import_multiple_value_separator' => '',
            '_import_empty_attribute_value_constant' => '__EMPTY__VALUE__',
            'import_images_file_dir' => ''

        ];
        $this->import->setData($data);
        //Images can be read only from given directory.
        $this->import->setData('images_base_directory', $this->imagesDirProvider->getDirectory());
        $errorAggregator = $this->import->getErrorAggregator();
        $errorAggregator->initValidationStrategy(
            $this->import->getData(Import::FIELD_NAME_VALIDATION_STRATEGY),
            $this->import->getData(Import::FIELD_NAME_ALLOWED_ERROR_COUNT)
        );
        try {
            $this->import->importSource();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->info('Something went wrong while importing products');
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Note : You should put your CSV file in `var` directory with name `product-csv.csv` and CSV format will as usual default magento 2 sample format.

Hope it's useful.

Thank You!